SSH server for cloning git repository over SSH
I want to build SSH server for cloning git repository over SSH.
command:
git clone git@localhost:/home/git/repo
My golang code that works.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os/exec"

    "github.com/gliderlabs/ssh"
)

func main() {
    ssh.Handle(func(s ssh.Session) {
        cmd := s.Command()
        if len(cmd) > 0 && cmd[0] == "git-upload-pack" {
            handleGitUploadPack(s, cmd[1])
        } else {
            io.WriteString(s, "Unknown command\n")
        }
    })

    log.Println("Starting SSH server on :22...")
    log.Fatal(ssh.ListenAndServe(":22", nil))
}

func handleGitUploadPack(s ssh.Session, repoPath string) {
    cmd := exec.Command("git-upload-pack", repoPath)
    cmd.Stdout = s
    cmd.Stderr = s
    cmd.Stdin = s

    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        io.WriteString(s, fmt.Sprintf("Failed to run git-upload-pack: %v\n", err))
    }
}

I want to rewrite the code above in rust using russh library.
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::Arc;

use anyhow::Result;
use async_trait::async_trait;
use russh::server::{Msg, Server as _, Session};
use russh::*;
use russh_keys::*;
use tokio::sync::Mutex;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    env_logger::builder()
        .filter_level(log::LevelFilter::Debug)
        .init();

    let config = russh::server::Config {
        inactivity_timeout: Some(std::time::Duration::from_secs(3600)),
        auth_rejection_time: std::time::Duration::from_secs(3),
        auth_rejection_time_initial: Some(std::time::Duration::from_secs(0)),
        keys: vec![russh_keys::key::KeyPair::generate_ed25519().unwrap()],
        ..Default::default()
    };
    let config = Arc::new(config);

    let mut sh = Server {
        clients: Arc::new(Mutex::new(HashMap::new())),
        id: 0,
    };

    sh.run_on_address(config, ("0.0.0.0", 22)).await.unwrap();

    Ok(())
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Server {
    clients: Arc<Mutex<HashMap<(usize, ChannelId), russh::server::Handle>>>,
    id: usize,
}

impl server::Server for Server {
    type Handler = Self;
    fn new_client(&mut self, _: Option<std::net::SocketAddr>) -> Self {
        let s = self.clone();
        self.id += 1;
        s
    }
}

#[async_trait]
impl server::Handler for Server {
    type Error = anyhow::Error;

    async fn channel_open_session(
        &mut self,
        channel: Channel<Msg>,
        session: &mut Session,
    ) -> Result<bool, Self::Error> {
        {
            let mut clients = self.clients.lock().await;
            clients.insert((self.id, channel.id()), session.handle());
        }
        Ok(true)
    }

    async fn auth_publickey(
        &mut self,
        _: &str,
        _: &key::PublicKey,
    ) -> Result<server::Auth, Self::Error> {
        Ok(server::Auth::Accept)
    }

    async fn exec_request(
        &mut self,
        channel: ChannelId,
        data: &[u8],
        session: &mut Session,
    ) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        // How to handle `git-upload-pack ./repo/path` command here.
        Ok(())
    }
}

In code above when i execute git clone git@localhost:/home/git/repo the exec_request function will be called and the value of data will be git-upload-pack /home/git/repo.
How can i handle git-upload-pack command in exec_request function?

Why aren't you running a real ssh server, which is easy, secure, and well-tested?

I have more complex logic than the example above, such as handling permissions for repositories for each user to ensure that users do not access private repositories owned by other users.

There is a ton of totally extraneous detail here. Your question is really quite simple - how do you take a data: &[u8] which probably could contain something that looks like shell command, and execute that shell command. You have included a ton of boilerplate from the russh library but what have you tried to actually process the data: &[u8]?

@crabrs you can still have a custom executable that handles your business logic with a standard SSH server, maybe you can look at how gitea or gitlab handle this. No need to write a while SSH server.

@user2407038 i want to know the equal of rust for this: cmd := exec.Command("git-upload-pack", repoPath)
cmd.Stdout = s
cmd.Stderr = s
cmd.Stdin = s

«handling permissions for repositories for each user» gitolite does that easily based on the public parts of the users' SSH keys. It basically provides for very lightweight no-frills "Git virtual hosting".
